# WooCommerce: Display product total price in cart/minicart instead of product price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce on my Wordpress site and I want to display the total price per product in my cart/minicart (e.g.: 'Product Quantity' x 'Product Price' = 'Product Total Price').
The code I am using right now is working, but there are rounding errors.

Expected:

- Product #1
- Quantity: 2
- Price: 3,50
- **Total Price: 7,00**

Displayed:

- Product #2
- Quantity: 2
- Price: 3,50
- **Total Price: 6,00**

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php $new_product_price_old = number_format((float)wp_kses( woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ), array() ) * $cart_item['quantity'], 2, ',', '.'); ?>
<?php echo '<span class="sidecart-item-price">' . $new_product_price ?>&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
```

Is there a simple way to fix this or maybe another piece of code? Or a hook I am missing? Total beginner here...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this myself. I don't know where I got my previous code from, but I guess this part was causing the issue:

```
wp_kses( woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ), array()
```

Here is my working code (I am a beginner, so there might be a better way to do this):

```
<?php   
$product_price_single = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
$product_price_total_formatted = number_format($product_price_single * $cart_item['quantity'], 2, ',', '.'); 
?>

<?php echo '<span>' . $product_price_total_formatted ?>&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
```